# Amazon syn between regions

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-rds

We have an app on amazon servers on US-east region.
The whole setup contains 2 ec2 instances behind a load balancer, an rds instance and an elasticcache instance which are all located in the US-east region.
We now see a lot of traffic from Japan so we need to focus on the slow latency that users there have.
Can anyone recommend a setup that will reduce the latency?
I think that just creating an ec2 instance in Japan will be slow as it will need to connect to RDS over region (I will use route 53 to route to closest gegraphically server).
Is there a builtin solution for master-master replication on RDS ?If not any other recommendations?

Comment: maybe just don't user RDS, use rather a master/master replication configured on usual ec2 instances where one master will be in the us-east-1 region and the other will be in the Tokyo region. and further create the application in the Tokyo region also after which connect it to the DB sever which you created there.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to use RDS, use rather a master/master replication configured on usual ec2 instances where one master will be in the us-east-1 region and the other will be in the Tokyo region. Further create the application in the Tokyo region and connect it to the DB sever which you created there.